# An error occurred while uploading the image in Sitecore Media Library

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I want to manually upload an image into specific folder in the Sitecore Media Library.

While uploading the image I am getting an error saying **An error occurred while uploading a file. The reason may be the that the file does not exist or the path is wrong**.

Please see the screenshot below:
[image]

I have tried to change some configuration settings in the **Sitecore.Speak.Applications.config** file but still having the same issue.

Please advise what can be causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a similar error in the past and in my case it was caused by a duplicate item name in the Media Library folder.

Image names in each media folder should be unique. If you try to upload a file with the name that already exists in the selected folder, Sitecore will return the message saying "**the file does not exist or the path is wrong**".
If this is the problem, you will see the error `Sitecore.Exceptions.DuplicateItemNameException` in Sitecore log file:

```
35220 12:30:19 ERROR Could not save posted file: test.png
Exception: Sitecore.Exceptions.DuplicateItemNameException
Message: The item name "test" is already defined on this level.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemUtil.AssertDuplicateItemName(Item destinationItem, Item sourceItem, String name)
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemUtil.AssertItemName(Item destinationItem, Item sourceItem, String name)
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.Add(String name, TemplateID templateID)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator.CreateItem(String itemPath, String filePath, MediaCreatorOptions options)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator.AttachStreamToMediaItem(Stream stream, String itemPath, String fileName, MediaCreatorOptions options)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator.CreateFromStream(Stream stream, String filePath, MediaCreatorOptions options)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUploader.UploadToDatabase(List`1 list)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUploader.Upload()
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.Save.Process(UploadArgs args)
```

**UPDATE:**

I double checked when this error message is used, and it can be caused by any exception thrown during media item creation. Some exceptions are thrown during item name validation: for example, if file name is too long (setting `MaxItemNameLength`), name ends with `.`, name starts or ends with spaces or tabs, name contains invalid characters (setting `InvalidItemNameChars`) or name does not match pattern from the setting `ItemNameValidation`.

So you can try uploading another file or renaming your file to a simple file name containing only letters and see if it helps.

Comment: @ Anna Gevel, in my case there is no image inside the folder this is completely blank or empty now

Comment: @KartikAgarwal that's interesting, do you see any error messages in Sitecore log file?

Comment: No there is no related log file into the log folder

Comment: @KartikAgarwal I double checked when this error message is used, and it can be caused by any exception thrown during media item creation. Some of them are: too long file name, name ending with ".", name starting or ending with spaces or tabs, name containing invalid characters (by default they are \ / : ? " < > | [ ]). So you can try uploading another file or renaming your file to a simple file name containing only letters and see if it helps.